# How best to iterate over three dimensional grid?

Tags: c++, mesh, eigen

My problem is to iterate through $[0.95,1] \times [0.95,1] \times[0.95,1] \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$. Is there a generic way to do this? I was considering rolling it all out and effectively vectorising the problem.

I would like to use Eigen but I think using a `vector` of `MatrixXd` elements seems not wise.

Any tips or help would be appreciated!

Comment: There are infinitely many values in this box. It's going to take me a while to verify that the algorithm I have in mind actually works... stand by...

Comment: Yes it shall take some discretization. I look forward to your idea Wolfgang

Comment: I think you have to explain more what you want to do. A triple loop sounds like a good starting point, but since nobody has an idea what your goal is, there's nothing we can help.

Comment: I have done more research Wolfgang and found that I need to have a structured, rectangular mesh. So I don't need to have anything fancy but if you or others know a way to create a box mesh using a decent C++ library, I would be very grateful to know.

Comment: Why create a mesh data structure? Why not just use a triple loop?

Comment: Is that the most efficient way? Thank you Wolfgang

Comment: The question is "the most efficient way for *what*?" I just don't see where you are going. A triple loop just incrementing a few `double` variables cannot be beaten by any kind of complicated data structure. But since I/anyone don't know what you want to do, we really can't help yuo.